# How to get an specific amount of lines in the console with less?

Tags: less

Can I get the specified number lines at a time by using the less command? I want just ex. show 20 lines even if my screen allows more.

Comment: when less it started the line numbers displayed, and the total number of lines is reported at bottom of screen.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to do, it does not seem like less is the correct tool for the job.

Comment: `ls | head 40 | tail 10` will show entries 31-40, but maybe I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Anthon I am not new SE. I am here from almost 2 years. Thank you. & by the way I am giving votes also.

Comment: only one down vote ???? give me 10 or 20 people . this is a very bad question. give it.

Comment: If you think it is worth 20 downvotes, either fix the question or delete it.

Comment: I started working with the tail command. Then, to get a range I ended up with a nice command using the less command as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043173/tail-f-filename-print-line-number-as-well The problem with the less command became getting a specific amount. I ended up with this same question. Being new to these commands I could not have understood their nature. Thank you rɑːdʒɑ for your question. It was nice to see that someone else thought of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

less works with screens of text. The "screen" is the full size of the terminal.

`less --window=n` can tell less to only use so many rows at a time. That being said the option is not always available.

see `man less`

If you only want "some" output try `tail -n 20 /file.txt` for the last 20 lines, or I personally use `head -n 20 | tail -n 10` to get the middle 10 lines.

Comment: I am sure there is a way to tell the terminal to only be so many rows, but that seems like a lot of work.

Comment: But `less --window=N` (or `less -zN` equivalently) doesn't (unfortunately) limit the number of strings initially shown on screen. It only affects how many lines it scrolls. What if I want to hide lines after N initially, and then scroll by N? `LINES` environment variable unfortunately has no effect (as per the man page, because it gets this info directly from the terminal device).

Comment: correct. You can change the window size but it still loads the entire house

Comment: For clarification: head -n 20 cuts everything after line 20 and tail -n 10 cuts from the remaining 20 lines everything before line 11 (including line nr. 10). So you end up with an absolute of 10 lines: Lines 11,12,...,20

Answer (score 2):

Display a file from line number X:

```
less +X filename
```

Use the -N option to output line numbers

```
e.g less +15000 -N filename
```

displays from line number 15000 with line numbers displayed

Comment: thank you , how about output from terminal & not from a file ? can i still use this ?

Comment: yes works fine from a terminal. e.g. `cat filename | less +15000 -N`

Comment: terminal output from some commands. Not from a file.

Comment: yes the same principle applies `ps | less +2`

Answer (score 1):

from less manual, to scroll n lines at a time, but shows a whole screen-full.

-[z]n or --window=n

Changes the default scrolling window size to n lines.  The default is one screenful.  The z and w commands can also be used to change the window size.  The "z" may be omitted for compatibility with  some  versions  of  more.  If the number n is negative, it indicates n lines less than the current screen size.  For example, if the screen is 24 lines, -z-4 sets the scrolling window  to 20  lines.   If the screen is resized to 40 lines, the scrolling window automatically changes to 36 lines.

Comment: But `less --window=N` (or `less -zN` equivalently) doesn't (unfortunately) limit the number of strings initially shown on screen. It only affects how many lines it scrolls. What if I want to hide lines after N initially, and then scroll by N? `LINES` environment variable unfortunately has no effect (as per the man page, because it gets this info directly from the terminal device).